# Alternative to ceil() and floor() to get the closest integer values, above and below of a floating point value?

Tags: c, algorithm, floor, ceil

I´m looking for an alternative for the `ceil()` and `floor()` functions in C, due to I am not allowed to use these in a project.

What I have build so far is a tricky back and forth way by the use of the cast operator and with that the conversion from a floating-point value (in my case a `double`) into an `int` and later as I need the closest integers, above and below the given floating-point value, to be also `double` values, back to `double`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   double original = 124.576;
   double floorint;
   double ceilint;
   int f;
   int c;

   f = (int)original;            //Truncation to closest floor integer value
   c = f + 1;
   floorint = (double)f;
   ceilint = (double)c;

   printf("Original Value: %lf, Floor Int: %lf , Ceil Int: %lf", original, floorint, ceilint);
}
```

Output:

```
Original Value: 124.576000, Floor Int: 124.000000 , Ceil Int: 125.000000
```

For this example normally I would not need the ceil and floor integer values of `c` and `f` to be converted back to `double` but I need them in `double` in my real program. Consider that as a requirement for the task.

---

Although the output is giving the desired values and seems right so far, I´m still in concern if this method is really that right and appropriate or, to say it more clearly, if this method does bring any bad behavior or issue into the program or gives me a performance-loss in comparison to other alternatives, if there are any other possible alternatives.

---

Do you know a better alternative? And if so, why this one should be better?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `_mm_round_sd` if seriously

Comment: @Sopel What shall i do with `_mm_round_sd`?

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica what if input is 124!!!!

Comment: @ManthanTilva Well, i guess, you´re right, i should provide an condition, that the ceil value should only be + 1 of the value for floor if the original value is a "true" floating-point value. Else the ceil value should be equivalent to the floor value. For the floor value there should be no important difference at that case.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica: Absolutely. That's what the expression `0.0 + i + (f != i)` does in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do you know a better alternative? And if so, why this one should be better?

OP'code fails:

- `original` is already a whole number.
- `original` is a negative like `-1.5`.  Truncation is not floor there.
- `original` is just outside `int` range.
- `original` is not-a-number.

---

Alternative construction

`double my_ceil(double x)`

Using the cast to some integer type trick is a problem when `x` is outsize the integer range. So check first if `x` is inside range of a wide enough integer (one whose precision exceeds `double`).  `x` values outside that are already whole numbers.  Recommend to go for the widest integer `(u)intmax_t`.

Remember that a cast to an integer is a round toward 0 and not a *floor*.  Different handling needed   if `x` is negative/positive when code is `ceil()` or `floor()`. OP's code missed this.

I'd avoid `if (x >= INTMAX_MAX) {` as that involves `(double) INTMAX_MAX` whose rounding and then precise value is "chosen in an implementation-defined manner".  Instead, I'd compare against `INTMAX_MAX_P1`.   `some_integer_MAX` is a [Mersenne Number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MersenneNumber.html) and with 2's complement, `...MIN` is a negated "power of 2".

```
#include <inttypes.h>

#define INTMAX_MAX_P1 ((INTMAX_MAX/2 + 1)*2.0)

double my_ceil(double x) {
  if (x >= INTMAX_MAX_P1) {
    return x;
  }
  if (x < INTMAX_MIN) {
    return x;
  }

  intmax_t i = (intmax_t) x;      // this rounds towards 0
  if (i < 0 || x == i) return i;  // negative x is already rounded up.
  return i + 1.0;
}
```

As `x` may be a [not-a-number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), it is more useful to reverse the compare as relational compare of a NaN is false.

```
double my_ceil(double x) {
  if (x >= INTMAX_MIN && x < INTMAX_MAX_P1) {
    intmax_t i = (intmax_t) x;      // this rounds towards 0
    if (i < 0 || x == i) return i;  // negative x is already rounded up.
    return i + 1.0;
  }
  return x;
}

double my_floor(double x) {
  if (x >= INTMAX_MIN && x < INTMAX_MAX_P1) {
    intmax_t i = (intmax_t) x;      // this rounds towards 0
    if (i > 0 || x == i) return i;  // positive x is already rounded down.
    return i - 1.0;
  }
  return x;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that in-depth explanation. Yes, that´s what I have asked for, as i just do not know all circumstances as a beginner. I´ll need a while to go through the separate steps and understand them in detail. Thank you very much, chux!

Comment: @chqrlie Yes - that is better.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing an important step: you need to check if the number is already integral, so for `ceil` assuming non-negative numbers (generalisation is trivial), use something like

```
double ceil(double f){
    if (f >= LLONG_MAX){
        // f will be integral unless you have a really funky platform
        return f;
    } else {
        long long i = f;
        return 0.0 + i + (f != i); // to obviate potential long long overflow
    }
}
```

Another missing piece in the puzzle, which is covered off by my enclosing `if`, is to check if `f` is within the bounds of a `long long`. On common platforms if `f` was outside the bounds of a `long long` then it would be integral anyway.

Note that `floor` is trivial due to the fact that truncation to `long long` is always towards zero.

Comment: First thank you very much for your answer. Why are these two things are so important to the case? Why is it bad if i omit them? This isn´t so clear for me.

Comment: ~@RobertS-ReinstateMonica: The version I present is good to go assuming 64 bit IEEE754 floating point double.

Comment: There is also the conundrum of how to handle NaNs and infinities.

Comment: @th33lf: Indeed. Writing a portable `ceil` is a pain. A C standard library has it easy in that they can ignore portability.

Comment: @Bathsheba What is the benefit of using a `long long int` instead of a normal `int` here in that case?

Comment: @Bathsheba Also: Your answer is seemingly only about the "ceiling". Is there anything to improve for the "flooring" technique as in my example? I´m not really trust in mine or are these wrong worries?

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica: Flooring is more trivial as truncation to `long long` is always towards zero.

Comment: But you should still change the test above to if (f<=-LLONG_MIN || f>=LLONG_MAX) {....

Comment: @HansOlsson: handling negative numbers is not so simple for `ceil` because the formula `0.0 + i + (f != i)` only works for `f >= 0`. For `f < 0` one should just use `(double)i`

Comment: @chqrlie - To handle that also update the  return statement to e.g. return 0.0+i+(i<0?0.0:(f!=i)); - or some other variant. Currently the code just says that it is trivial to handle negative numbers, but doesn't say how.

Answer (score 1):

If we need to find the ceil value of a/b, then we can use **(a+b-1)/b** instead of using **ceil** function.

Enjoy. No need to use double or float.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Interesting approach, but it only works for integers and has some potential problems with `a + b` giving an overflow.